# Python HTML parsing from url

Tags: python, html, parsing

I've heard it's possible to get data from a link. But I want to know the best method, I've read about that, but I still want to know how and what's the best module to do so. I want to parse this:

```
<div class="blalbal"><h2>DATA5</h2>
<div class="blabla">
<table class="tabledata">
<tr><th>Blablabla:</th><td>DATA3<br>(DATA4)</td></tr>
<tr><th>Blablabla:</th><td>DATA2</td></tr>
<tr><th>Blablabla:</th><td>DATA1</td></tr>
</td>
```

as a string, like DATA1, DATA2, DATA3 (DATA4), DATA5

So, I'd want to see how is this possible (just an example) and what's the best & fastest method. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  There are a number of packages that can do this a number of different ways.  Though they all generally require you start with well formed content (there are 3 missing close tags here).

Comment: No I just gave an example, obv the tags are not closed.

Comment: Try to make an effort and google it. You will find tons of  different ways to do it.

Comment: @root, I've done that already, but since my question includes THE BEST way and the FASTEST (probably you haven't seen it because you just read the title only), I asked here.

Comment: @RewriteRule -- use `lxml.html` if you want the fastest/most powerful. now, you should be able to find it yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From Python [HTMLParser Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html):

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

# create a subclass and override the handler methods
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Encountered a start tag:", tag
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print "Encountered an end tag :", tag
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print "Encountered some data  :", data

# instantiate the parser and fed it some HTML
parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
            '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
```

In your case you can just use the `handle_data` function to print HTML contents.

Comment: This will fail on every piece of real world data. I really wouldn't recommend anything in the standard lib for parsing html.