# HTML Parsing: from source to text in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, python-3.x

I already read this question ([Python HTML parsing from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360518/python-html-parsing-from-url)) but I have not understood something. This is the code:

```
import urllib.request
from html.parser import HTMLParser
    # create a subclass and override the handler methods
    class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
            def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
                print ("Encountered a start tag:"+ tag)
            def handle_endtag(self, tag):
                print ("Encountered an end tag :"+ tag)
            def handle_data(self, data):
                print ("Encountered some data  :"+ data)
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    info = "http://www.calendario-365.it/js/365.php?page=moon"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(info)
    content = response.read()
    parser.feed(str(content))
```

Applying this code to my website gives me this :
http://pastebin.com/m4YV38uM
I want to save into variables

> 10,6 giorni
>
> 82%

How? Thanks for answers. Python version: 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Though regexes are terse and parsers like LXML and Beautifulsoup are convenient, *in this particular problem*, I wouldn't mind using `HTMLParser`. Even if you don't end up using it, here is the procedure. There is a little bit of subtlety involved in using it. If the target element is as follows(as you have not shown the actual element I am assuming one)

```
<div id="x" class="y"> 82% </div>
```

Then, implement the methods as follows

```
Class My(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.percent = 0
        self.flag = False

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        attrs = dict(attrs) # {"id": someid, "class": someclass}
        if attrs.get("id") == "x": # or attrs.get("class") == "y"
            self.flag = True # we entered the target

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.flag == True: # we are inside our target
            self.percent = data # do str -> int conversion

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if self.flag == True: # reached the end of target
            self.flag = False
```

For each value you want to capture

1. Add an instance attribute (like `self.percent`)
2. Add a flag (like `self.flag`)
3. Implement the corresponding logic in all the three methods: to identify entry, to extract data, and to identify exit.

Answer (score -1):

OK if you're looking for a simple solution you can just run a regular expression over your results, or use it to limit your output to begin with. I can't really tell how you are outputting this data, but you might want to try these patterns:

```
"\d?\d,\d giorni"
"\d?\d%"
```

The first one should find any pattern of one or two digits followed by a comma and another digit, the second one one or two digits followed by %. You can also use the "+" or "*" operators instead, depending on the variability in your input.

Comment: This is not an answer ... Please, if you intended to get more information from OP do post it as comments, otherwise if you cannot, do not post it as answer.

Comment: Those two elements can change every day, for example "82%" after can be "54%" or "100%". Maybe the two (or 3) numbers before "%"? Or maybe the three digits before "giorni"? I don't know if there are true criteria :)

Comment: @ Iron Fist: My bad, I'm new here. This was not intended to be an answer. Seems like it does not let me comment because of low status though...

Comment: What? I don't understand

Comment: When I try to comment on the original post, it tells me that I need 50 reputation to post a comment. But I have edited my question into an answer by now.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions is generally discouraged. Since equivalent-looking HTML can contain variations in whitespace, case, attribute order, and quoting, using and maintaining a regex can be a challenge. HTML parsers like BeautifulSoup are the more preferred approach.

Comment: I agree, but understood that the OP wanted to search through an output he had already created. A regular expression seemed the easiest approach.

Comment: I did not understand where I have to put those codes

Comment: You can use those to search through a text like this:
`pattern= see above
string='this is the string we want to search through'
results=re.findall(pattern , string)`
See also [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) here.

Comment: hello = list(content).findall("\d?\d,\d giorni")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'findall'

Comment: You need to feed it a string. Try merging your list into a string first using `" ".join(list)`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
# -- coding: UTF-8 --
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.calendario-365.it/js/365.php?page=moon').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

print(soup.find(text='Età della Luna:').findNext('div').text)

print(soup.find(text='Percentuale visibile:').findNext('div').text)
```

Output:

```
10,6 giorni
82%
```

Comment: Syntax error:
print *soup*.find(text='Età della Luna:').findNext('div').text

Comment: May be you are using python3, see the updated answer. Also make sure if you have bs4 .

Comment: Can you give me the download link of Beautifulsoup? Because I don't have those module

Comment: return super(HTMLParserTreeBuilder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'
What?

Comment: This is the code: (I  used urllib.request because I don't have urllib2):
http://pastebin.com/bRsAavCd